# Can anyone explain why the program is returning this error ?? The Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c

Can anyone explain why the program is returning this error ?? (The Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) )

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    void what(int A[])
    {
        int i=0,j=0; int temp=0;
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
            j=i-1;
            while(j>=0 && A[j]>A[j+1])
            {
                temp=A[j];
                A[j]=A[j+1];
                A[j+1]=temp;
                j+j-1;
            }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<=4;k++)
            printf(A[k]);
    }
    int S[5]={20,10,20,30,15};
    what(S);
}
```

Comment: First of all, nested functions are not standard. Second, `j+j-1;` does nothing. You probably wanted to assign the result somewhere, or do `j=j-1;`.

Comment: `printf(A[k])` ->`printf("%d\n", A[k]);`. Look at the printf examples in your learning material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your program works correctly in sorting if you fix the problem at the time of initialization variable `j`

```
 j = j-1;
```

also print the array elements like following:

```
   printf("%i ", A[k]);
```

use above statement to print array element.